# Issue with vim setup python ide

Tags: windows, vim, python, vimrc, vim-plugins

Found ale lint on git about vim but the display after clone from git is still shown as classic instead of the one shown on:

[image: vim display how to configure]

The syntax suggestion is not on as well
Do I need to run ale toggle to turn on ale?